# How to use less.render with promises in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, less, promise

I am trying to use Promises with less.render in Node.js, but I am not getting the CSS returned that I would expect.

Here is the result I am getting:

```
{ domain: null, _events: {}, _maxListeners: 10 }
```

And this is the code block I am using:

```
var q = require("q")  
  , less = require("less")  
  ;

var less_css = "@background: #131313; body{background:@background;}";

q.resolve( less.render(less_css) )
  .then(function(output_css) {

    // [UNEXPECTED RESULTS]
    console.log(output_css);

  },function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
  });
```

However, when I do it without the promises (as a regular old callback), it works...

```
var less = require("less");  

var css = "@background: #131313; body{background:@background;}";  

less.render(css, function(err, css_output){  
  console.log( css_output );  
});
```

This block outputs the following css, which is what I was expecting from the promise:

```
body {
  background: #131313;
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Update:

Things worked as expected when switching to less version 2.0.0-b1.

See more details here:

https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2271#issuecomment-61762681

Comment: After reading B. Gruenbaum's answer, I got the following code to work with less@1.7.5.

    var Promise = require("bluebird"), less = require("less");

      function renderLess(css){
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
           less.render(css,function(err,data){
              if(err !== null) return reject(err);;
              resolve(data);
           });
        });
      } 

      var stuff = Promise.resolve(renderLess(css))
      .then(function(css_output){
        console.log(css_output);
       }, function(err){});